# How to create a new list from list1 - list 2 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the list1= [com.x1 ,com.x2 com.x3] and i have the one more list list2= [com.x3].

i need the one more list as list3=[com.x1 , com.x2 ] like list1-list2.

Please help me in this.

Comment: did you hear about set?

Comment: You can use list comprehensions or generator expressions(if you are dealing with big list)  `[x for x in list1 if x not in list2] ` or `(x for x in list1 if x not in list2) `.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List comprehension will do:

```
[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```